# Почему получение данных в python socket останавливается?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет, request

Пишу небольшой сервер на python 3 с использованием модуля socket.

server.py:

```
import socket
from views import *
URLS = {
    '/': index,
    '/blog': blog,
    '/favicon.ico': favicon,
    '/index.css': index_css
}

def generate_content(code, url):
    if code == 404:
        return '<h1>404</h1><p>Not found</p>'
    if code == 405:
        return '<h1>405</h1><p>Method not allowed</p>'
    # return '<h1>{}</h1>'.format(URLS[url])
    return URLS[url]()

def generate_headers(method, url):
    if method != 'GET':
        return ('HTTP/1.1 405 Method not allowed\r\n\r\n', 405)

    if url not in URLS:
        return('HTTP/1.1 404 Not found\r\n\r\n', 404)

    return ('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n', 200)

def parse_request(request):
    parsed = request.split(' ')
    method = parsed[0]
    url = parsed[1]
    return (method, url)

def generate_response(request):
    method, url = parse_request(request)
    headers, code = generate_headers(method, url)
    body = generate_content(code, url)
    return (headers + body).encode()

def run():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind(('localhost', 5000))
    server_socket.listen(10)

    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
        while True:
            # client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
            request = client_socket.recv(1024)
            if not request:
                break
            print(request.decode('utf-8'))
            print(addr)

            response = generate_response(request.decode('utf-8'))
            client_socket.sendall(response)
            # client_socket.close()
        client_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

views.py:

```
import os


dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)


def index():
    with open(os.path.join(dir,'templates/index.html'), encoding='utf-8') as template:
        return template.read()

def blog():
    with open(os.path.join(dir,'templates/blog.html'), encoding='utf-8') as template:
        return template.read()

def index_css():
    with open(os.path.join(dir,'templates/index.css'), encoding='utf-8') as index_css:
        return index_css.read()

def favicon():
    with open(os.path.join(dir,'templates/favicon.ico')) as favicon:
        return favicon.read()
```

Проблема внутри цикла whlie.
Если я запускаю код как есть и перехожу на localhost:5000, то завершается первая итерация внутреннего цикла while, и во время второй итерации код останавливается на получении запроса `request = client_socket.recv(1024)`. Запрос со стороны клиента есть, это видно в Chrome DevTools. Там первый запрос завершился нормально, а у второй на рассмотрении.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И на этом все. В браузере страница просто бесконечно грузится, а в консоли никаких ошибок.

Если основной код немного изменить на такой вариант:

```
while True:
# client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
while True:
    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
    request = client_socket.recv(1024)
    if not request:
        break
    print(request.decode('utf-8'))
    print(addr)

    response = generate_response(request.decode('utf-8'))
    # client_socket.sendall('hello world'.encode())
    client_socket.sendall(response)
    client_socket.close()
# client_socket.close()
```

То все работает нормально, но это немного нелогично, на мой взгляд, т.к. при получении каждого нового пакета соединение с клиентом устанавливается заново.
Посмотрел [примеры](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example) в документации и там тоже не делают `socket.accept()` и `recv()` внутри одного цикла.

Так почему мой код останавливается на второй итерации на получении запроса `request = client_socket.recv(1024)`, хотя запрос отправлен?

Comment: Попробуйте client_socket.setblocking(0)

Comment: @АлексейМ. в таком случае при попытке подключения к серверу он сразу падает с ошибкой `request = client_socket.recv(1024)
BlockingIOError: [WinError 10035] Операция на незаблокированном сокете не может быть завершена немедленно`

Comment: @АлексейМ. попробовал код из последнего блока и все равно на втором GET запросе все время висит статус `(pending)` и страница бесконечно загружается.

Comment: Вот решение через asyncio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506460/python-simple-socket-client-server-using-asyncio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так это должно выглядеть:

```
import socket
import select

from views import *

# ...

def run():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind(('localhost', 5000))
    server_socket.listen(10)

    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
        client_socket.setblocking(0)
        while True:
            ready = select.select([client_socket], [], [], 1)
            if ready[0]:
                request = client_socket.recv(1024)
                if not request:
                    break
                print(request.decode('utf-8'))
                print(addr)

                response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK \r\nContent-Type: text/html; " + \
                    "charset=utf-8 \r\n\r\n<h2>Localhost!</h2>"
                client_socket.sendall(response.encode('utf-8'))
            else:
                break
        client_socket.close()
```

Под свои нужды уже сами поправьте.

Comment: Почему бы, не `0`, а `False` -> `client_socket.setblocking(False)`? :) https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking Понятно, что и так работает, но ведь с толку может сбивать `int` -- вдруг он несет сакральный смысл

Comment: Тут уж дело вкуса. Насчёт сакрального смысла, даже задумался ))

Comment: @АлексейМ. большое спасибо! А не подскажите, почему без этого "хака" с `select` нормально не работает? Теоретически на первой итерации сервер должен принять запрос на html документ, на второй итерации на css, а на третьей на favicon, но почему то на второй итерации он вечно ждет запроса, хотя судя по DevTools запрос отправлен.

Comment: @ЕгорСпириади, select -  это системный вызов для опроса дескрипторов на предмет готовности к чтению или записи. Либо на каждый запрос нужно создавать клиентский сокет, либо вешать его в неблокирующем режиме и проверять готовность в течение какого-то времени. Время, в течение которого сокет будет проверяться устанавливаем последним параметром select.select([client_socket], [], [], 1) - здесь одна секунда.